# cassandra-4.0-beta4 Exception encountered during startup Requested permits (0) must be positive

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-4.0

- OS：Ubuntu20.04
- JDK：JDK11
- Cassandra version: apache-cassandra-4.0-beta4

Error message:

```
ERROR [main] 2021-03-25 14:16:15,561 CassandraDaemon.java:822 - Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.TruncateException: Error during truncate: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested permits (0) must be positive
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.TruncateStatement.executeLocally(TruncateStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.executeInternal(QueryProcessor.java:323)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.clearAllEstimates(SystemKeyspace.java:1337)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.cleanupSizeEstimates(StorageService.java:3908)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:353)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:676)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:800)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested permits (0) must be positive
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.runWithCompactionsDisabled(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2329)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.runWithCompactionsDisabled(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2276)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.truncateBlocking(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2256)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.TruncateStatement.executeLocally(TruncateStatement.java:92)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested permits (0) must be positive
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:189)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.checkPermits(RateLimiter.java:430)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.reserve(RateLimiter.java:285)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.acquire(RateLimiter.java:273)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.snapshotWithoutFlush(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1801)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.snapshot(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1981)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.snapshot(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1957)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.snapshot(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1945)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$4.run(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2242)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.runWithCompactionsDisabled(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2325)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

Question was [also asked on the #cassandra channel](https://the-asf.slack.com/archives/CJZLTM05A/p1616673783296300) on [ASF Slack](https://cassandra.apache.org/community/) so I'm re-posting here for posterity.

Based on the stack trace, it looks like it's failing when trying to access the snapshot subdirectories of the `system.size_estimates` and `system.table_estimates`.

It's possible that the directories got corrupted as a result of the power outage (the reason for restarting the node in the first place) although I don't have sufficient information to confirm this.

In any case, the workaround is to manually delete the snapshot directories for the `size_estimates/` and `table_estimates/` in `data/system/*`. This will allow Cassandra to start successfully. Cheers!

P.S. 贾博超 confirmed on ASF Slack that the workaround allowed them to start C* on the node.

Comment: Thanks Erick!  I must have missed this one on the mailing list.

Comment: Not a problem. It was on Slack, actually. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this a restart of a failed node?  It looks like something is trying to replay a `TRUNCATE` command, but something required isn't being sent along (as per [CASSANDRA-14905](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14905)).

To get around this, I would remove the `system_schema` keyspace from the disk and restart.  It should re-stream the schema from another node.

If that doesn't work, you might end up having to wipe the data and rebuild the node.  And if that *still* doesn't work, you may have to remove/rejoin it to the cluster.

**Edit:**

As per Erick's answer, it looks like the problem was with snapshots directories for the `size_estimates` and `table_esimates` tables in the `system` keyspace.  Remove those, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed the same problem with a docker container. When I checked the logs

> docker logs 59d4e2890a34

it highlighted this issue. i.e.

```
INFO  [main] 2022-07-22 09:24:16,961 ColumnFamilyStore.java:2242 - Truncating system.size_estimates
INFO  [main] 2022-07-22 09:24:16,964 ColumnFamilyStore.java:2279 - Truncating system.size_estimates with truncatedAt=1658481856962
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.TruncateException: Error during truncate: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested permits (0) must be positive
```

Using

> docker container rm 59d4e2890a34

I removed the existing container and re-created it. The new version ran fine. I'm not sure what corrupted `system.size_estimates`.

Answer (score -2):

i found another solution

```
rm -rf apache-cassandra-4.0-beta4/data/saved_caches/*
rm -rf apache-cassandra-4.0-beta4/data/data/system/*
```

Comment: This isn't a solution because once you delete the contents of `data/system/`, you've effectively booted the node out of the cluster and it has to be bootstrapped again. Cheers!

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it